# Why does not uint16_t show the desired output?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, uint32, uint16

I have an array-

```
uint8_t arrayTest[] = {
    0, 0xC1,                
    0, 0, 0, 0x0a,          
    0, 0, 0, 0x50           
 };
```

So the following *printf* with **uint32_t** shows the correct output "**a**":

```
printf("%x ",ntohl(*((uint32_t *)(arrayTest+2))));
```

But **uint16_t**  does not show it correctly, although I forward the array pointer two fields, the output is "**a0000**"-

```
printf("%x ",ntohl(*((uint16_t *)(arrayTest+4))));
```

It is same when I use %d:

With `printf("%d ",ntohl(*((uint32_t *)(arrayTest+2))));` the output is "**10**"

With `printf("%d ",ntohl(*((uint16_t *)(arrayTest+4))));` the output is "**655360**"

Why???

Comment: [The usual integral conversions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n)...

Comment: You are invoking **undefined behaviour** here (dereferencing through those pointer casts).

Comment: `printf` is not a safe function. Be vewy vewy careful when using it. This includes [*reading the manual*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: Note that there's an ntohs() function for 16 bit data and ntohl() for 32 bit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nothl` is *only* for converting 32bit quantities. It will produce incorrect result for 16bit quantities, at least on little endian systems. Use `ntohs`for that.